# Need help to understand Vue.js function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an assignment to make calculator using vue.js. 
Much of it works, I'm confused about how to implement the '=' function.

I found this piece of code in an article that does something similar but I don't understand what it does. Can someone explain it?
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-scientific-calculator-with-vuejs

I found this Piece of code:

```
if ((app.current).indexOf("^") > -1) {
      var base = (app.current).slice(0, (app.current).indexOf("^"));
      var exponent = (app.current).slice((app.current).indexOf("^") + 1);
      app.current = eval("Math.pow(" + base + "," + exponent + ")");
    } else {
      app.current =app.current
    }
```

Can someone please explain what the above function does, line-by-line?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which part you don't understand? This looks like it's just breaking an exponent like `5^2` into `5` and `2`, and then doing an eval: `Math.pow(5,2)`

Comment: It check for power in input

Comment: This piece of code  calculates the power of a number if ^ sign is detected

Comment: And "The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object."

Comment: The eval is also unnecessary, even dangerous if `app.current` is the user input.

Comment: @LukeBriggs There was a comment left (with multiple upvotes/agreements) and two closure votes to supplement the downvotes, so I'd say the reasoning was quite evident. Not to mention [it's most often *discouraged* to explain your downvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not).

Comment: @TylerRoper I'm more of the opinion that new people need at least a little more guideance when it comes to their first question. I completely agree with constructive comments, but the answer to yours appeared to be an "all of it". This community could easily provide effective help in just a few minutes worth of comments, as seen below, but being downvoted repeatedly for a lack of specificness on 7 lines of code is overall a rather awful first experience of this site.

Answer (score 2):

```js
// checks if app.current have '^' by getting the index
// if the method indexOf doesn't find anything it return -1
if (app.current.indexOf('^') > -1) {
  // gets the first element till the index where it found '^'
  var base = app.current.slice(0, app.current.indexOf('^'));
  // gets the number after the 'ˆ'
  var exponent = app.current.slice(app.current.indexOf('^') + 1);
  // eval is evil
  // it gets the string and transfoms into valid code
  // wich means to do the operation
  app.current = eval('Math.pow(' + base + ',' + exponent + ')');
} else {
  // if it doesn't find the index it keeps the same value
  app.current = app.current;
}
```

https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: thank you, i understand it now. was irritated by the'^'